# Explanation on how import knows to go to package.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, import

I am drawing a blank in bed right now, and after a bunch of google searches and incomplete answers I decided to ask here.

Can anyone explain to me how the scoping works for import  in typescript to know to go check the package.json? For example, you do something like import * from ‘three’. What tells typescript to go to the package.json to check for three?

Answer (score 1):

When your `moduleResolution` is set to `node` the modules are required via `require()` like in *NodeJS*. The rest is explained in the documentation.

From the [**Documentation**](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a core module, and
>   does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then Node.js starts at the
>   parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and
>   attempts to load the module from that location. Node will not append
>   node_modules to a path already ending in node_modules.

Comment: This was not the best question to ask because I knew the answer, but was over complicating the process.

Answer: When the compiler compiles the typescript file it will try to locate the module that was imported. Node then tells the compiler where to find the module.

Thanks!